# Writing for FastCGI in VB6?

Tags: windows, iis, vb6, fastcgi

While I'm busy here reading the [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node/22) documentation (yeah, reading the 'friendly' manual), does anyone know whether anyone has had any success writing FastCGI apps in VB6?

Starting to get close to finding a solution myself at Coast Research and Development's [FastCGI Dll Library (with SIGTERM handler) for Windows Web Servers](http://www.coastrd.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Coast Research and Development](http://www.coastrd.com) have brought out a VB6 specific version of their FastCGI library.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed an MIT Licensed open-source FastCGI application server framework for VB6. It is available on GitHub here:

https://github.com/jpbro/VbFcgi